# How to assign networkish for provider?

Tags: ethers.js

Here is the doc about provider in ethers 5.x document:

```
new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider( [ urlOrConnectionInfo [ , networkish ] ] )

Connect to a JSON-RPC HTTP API using the URL or ConnectionInfo urlOrConnectionInfo connected to the networkish network.

If urlOrConnectionInfo is not specified, the default (i.e. http://localhost:8545) is used and if no network is specified, it will be determined automatically by querying the node using eth_chaindId and falling back on eth_networkId.
```

What is the `networkish` for urlOrConnectionInfo below?

```
let connectionInfo = {
              url: 'http://my-ip:80',
              headers: {
                "Bearer": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6...."  //<<==RS256 JWT token
              },       
            };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Ethers docs on [Networks](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/#providers--networks):

> Any API that accept a Networkish can be passed a common name (such as `"mainnet"` or `"ropsten"`) to use that network definition or may specify custom parameters.

From the source code [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/networks/src.ts/types.ts#L10) it looks like a `networkish` can be a few things:

- a string name (`"mainnet"`)
- a chain number (1)
- a `Network` object (defined right above a `networkish` in the code linked above):

```
export type Network = {
    name: string,
    chainId: number,
    ensAddress?: string,
    _defaultProvider?: (providers: any, options?: any) => any
}
```